# How many odd binary numbers with four zero's?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Question: How many 8-bit numbers are odd or have exactly 4 bits that equal 0?

Examples: 01001011 satisfies conditions, 01001110 and 01001111 do not.

---

**Progress:**

I can use inclusion-exclusion, I suppose. So:
 $$Odd\cup FourZeros = Odd + FourZeros - Odd\cap FourZeros$$

So I think that Odd = $2^7$, since the one's digit must be one, right?

And then I think FourZeros = ${8 \choose 4} = 70$, since we're choosing four from 8 total.

How do I find the union? Can I just pick four of the seven spots to place zeros and then randomly fill the other 3? ${7 \choose 4} * 2^3$? But that number is 280--too large to work with the inclusion-exclusion equation above (becasue 128 + 70 - 280 is below zero.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I think it's easier to just count the odd strings (easy, it just has to end in $1$) and then count the even strings with four $0's$.  These are disjoint so you can just add at the end.  Note:  you should clarify whether you mean exactly four or at least four. Also, your examples indicate that you are ok with starting with $0$...is that correct? (most people would write the binary number $(01001011)_2=(1001011)_2$ and say it had length $7$, not $8$.

Comment: @JulianStanley You mixed up the $\cap$ and $\cup$. The formula should be $Odd \cup FourZeroes = Odd + FourZeroes - Odd \cap FourZeroes$.

Comment: Actually, I think I don;t understand the question.  What does "...are both odd or contain four zero digits" mean?  I took it to mean what I sketched in my comment above, but I might have misunderstood.

Comment: @TobyMak Thanks, I think I fixed the signs.
lulu: Well they need to both be odd and have four zeros (including leading zeros is okay) so 00001111 counts, for example

Comment: Exactly four or at least four?

Comment: Exactly four.  Restated: 8-digit number that is odd (inclusive OR) has exactly 4 bits that equal 0

Comment: "Both X or Y" is strange. Usually, it is "Both X **and** Y"

Comment: So, just $\binom 74$ then, right?

Comment: Note:  your restatement just makes matters worse.  The Inclusive Or means what I sketched in my first comment.  That is, in this case, it means "all length $8$ binary strings that are either odd or have exactly four $0's$ or both".  Is that what you intended?

Comment: @lulu isn't the number of permutations of $r$ objects from an $n$-element set $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}=\binom{n}{r}r!$?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern  What am I permuting?  I have seven slots and I need to choose four in which to put my $0's$...that's the definition of $\binom 74$.

Comment: @lulu I'm pretty sure that $\binom{7}{4}$ wouldn't count $11100001$ and $11000011$ as distinct numbers.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern  What are you talking about?  Those are two different selections of slots so of course they represent two different choices.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern  Let's try a simpler example (one we can easily enumerate).  Say we want length $5$ binary strings which end in $1$ and have exactly two $0's$.  I say the answer is $\binom 42=6$.  Namely:  $11001,10101,01101,10011,01011,00111$ .  Did I miss any?

Comment: @lulu you missed $00111$, $01011$, $01101$

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern  All three of those appear in my list.  Enough.  Final comment.

Comment: @lulu just because your formula works for one case doesn't mean it works for all cases.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern  Please stop writing to me.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. Yes! that was misleading. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean both odd and have four one bits, you must have the last bit $1$ and can choose any three of the other seven, so there are ${7 \choose 3}=35$.  Your example indicates you allow leading zeros.

Added:  If you want either odd or four zeros there are $2^7$ odd ones because you just have to set the last bit.  Among the evens there are ${7 \choose 4}=35$ that have four zeros, so a total of $128+35=163$

Comment: So would this mean that, for the inclusive OR $$Odd\cup FourZeros = 128 + 70 - 35 = 163$$?

Comment: @JulianStanley what are you looking for? $\mathrm{Odd}\cup\mathrm{4\,zeros}$ or $\mathrm{Odd}\cap\mathrm{4\,zeros}$

Comment: The OR one (cup, not cap)

Answer (score 0):

Allowing leading zeroes (as per your example) and assuming that you mean ***exactly*** four zeroes, you know that the last (units) digit is $1$ and the four zeroes must go in $4$  of the remaining $7$ locations.

This is clearly just $\binom 74$.

Forbidding a leading zero will likewise get you to $\binom 64$.

Taking the challenge as ***at least*** four zeroes, for the numbers involved here, probably the simplest approach is to add up the cases of four zeroes, five zeroes, six zeroes and (if appropriate) seven zeroes.